# size for select drop down chrome

Tags: google-chrome, select, size, dropdown

I need to dynamically set size of the select drop down in my angular app. The condition is ,
size="{{array.length > 10?10:array.length}}"

If array has more than 10 values,  default the size to 10 
else
show all the elements in array.

This condition for size attribute works on IE, but fails on chrome. How to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Try add `height: auto` to the dropdown css style.